# Wilcoxon rank sum test

Tags: r

I'm performing pairwise Wilcoxon test with a simple data set and get surprising results. Comparing group A and C using the full set (A, B and C) returns a p-value different than comparing A and C with a data subset (A and C groups only).

```
dfx <- data.frame(group = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 15), rep('C', 6)), sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 29, replace = TRUE), age = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54))
pairwise.wilcox.test(dfx$age, dfx$group, pool.sd=F, paired=F)

Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 
data:  dfx$age and dfx$group 
  A    B   
B 0.55 -   
C 0.13 0.19
P value adjustment method: holm 

dfx.ac<-dfx[which(dfx$group!='B'),]
pairwise.wilcox.test(dfx.ac$age, dfx.ac$group, pool.sd=F, paired=F)

Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 
data:  dfx.ac$age and dfx.ab$group 
  A    
C 0.043
P value adjustment method: holm
```

Using Wilcoxon test on individual data returns the same p-value.

```
a<-dfx[which(dfx$group=='A'),]$age
c<-dfx[which(dfx$group=='C'),]$age
wilcox.test(a,c)
W = 8, p-value = 0.04262

wilcox.test(dfx.ac$age~dfx.ac$group)
W = 8, p-value = 0.04262
```

What do I do wrong with pairwise.wilcox.test(dfx$age, dfx$group, pool.sd=F, paired=F) ?

Same difference if I compare a set of 3 groups or 4 groups.
    dfx <- data.frame(
    group = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 15), rep('C', 6), rep('D', 9)),
    sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 38, replace = TRUE),
    age = runif(n = 38, min = 18, max = 54))

```
dfx.nb<-dfx[which(dfx$group!='B'),]

pairwise.wilcox.test(dfx$age,dfx$group, pool.sd=F, paired=F)
  A    B    C   
B 1.00 -    -   
C 0.57 0.62 -   
D 0.56 0.56 1.00

pairwise.wilcox.test(dfx.nb$age,dfx.nb$group, pool.sd=F, paired=F)
  A    C   
C 0.28 -   
D 0.28 0.95
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `?pairwise.wilcox.test`.  This function implements a correction for multiple comparison which accounts for the difference.

**Edited to add:**

When you make a single comparison, then a p-value of `P` can be interpreted to mean that the probability of obtaining the observed data under the null hypothesis of no effect equals `P`.  So if we want to make sure that the probability of observing our data under the null hypothesis of no effect is less than `0.05`, we simply have to check whether or not `p<0.05` (in statistics, we call the threshold for significance `alpha`, and frequently are interested in whether `p < alpha=0.05`).  But if you compare a large number of groups, then the probability that you will find **at least one** p-value less than `alpha` is much greater than alpha!

For example, imagine I do two independent comparisons.  If the null hypothesis is true, then each has a probability 0.05 of yielding a p-value less than `alpha=0.05`. But the chance that **at least one of them** will yield a p-value less than `alpha=0.05` is `1-0.95*0.95 =  0.0975`. So we have nearly a 1-in-10 chance of a type I error (if the null hypothesis is correct).  If we do 100 comparisons, we can be almost certain that we will commit a type I error if we interpret our p-values uncritically.

To avoid this, we can "adjust" the p-values to ensure that we control the type I error rate.  The most conservative option, known as Bonferroni correction, is to adjust `alpha` by dividing it by the number of comparisons we perform (which has an effect similar to multiplying our p-values by the number of comparisons).

`pairwise.wilcox.test` is automatically adjusting the p-values so that they can be interpreted against `alpha=0.05` without badly inflating the type I error rate.  The more comparisons you make, the more the p-values need to be adjusted in order to control the type 1 error rate.  [As an aside, note that the correction is a bit complicated, because the three comparisons are no longer fully independent of one another (you can see this by noting that `(a > b) & (b > c)` implies `a > c`).  In practice, we usually don't take this non-independence into account when we perform the adjustments.]

The adjustment method defines how `pairwise.wilcox.test` estimates the necessary adjustment.  Changing the adjustment method would change the details of how the necessary adjustment is estimated, and could change your p-values.  The adjustment method `Holm` presumably implements the [Holm-Bonferroni method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method).

Comment: In both case I use the Holm adjustment method. The only difference is that one set contains two groups, the other three groups. I did the same with 3 and 4 groups respectively.

Comment: But you are making a different number of comparisons in the two cases!  I will add an explanation of the logic and purpose of multiple test corrections to my answer.

Comment: Ok, would another adjustment function give the same results? I would to compare all groups with each other, as if I would loop through them using the wilco.test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long explanation. I'm not a statistician and unfortunately can't show the real data. I compare repeated independent experiments, which I display using box plots. Among these, I'd like to highlight box plots that are significantly different. Because the number of experiments is only repeated 6 to 10 times and I cannot assess the expected normal distribution, I selected Wicoxon test.

Comment: It's smart to use the Wilcoxon test.  Your choice of test doesn't change the problem of multiple comparisons.  You have two options.  One is to report the p-values from the single comparisons.  Bear in mind that this means that **even if there are no effects in your comparisons** the average number of 'significant' effects that you detect will be closer to alpha **times the number of comparisons** than to alpha.  So you could be presenting a bunch of 'significant' boxplots when actually there is no effect anywhere.

Comment: The second option is to use the corrections performed by pairwise.wilcox.test to adjust all of your p-values, so that you can assume that individual p-values less than alpha actually mean that there is a small probability (less than alpha) that the data could have been generated under the null hypothesis of no effect.